# Make android splash screen image cover the screen

Tags: android, react-native, expo, splash-screen

I build my app with expo react native, how can I make my splash screen image cover the screen on app launch, so that the white space above and below did not show:

**see Image below**

[image]

See code below **splashscreen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@color/splashscreen_background"/>
</layer-list>
```

I will appreciate if you help edit splashscreen.xml code for the answer thanks.

Comment: At top might be the status bar (https://docs.expo.dev/guides/configuring-statusbar/#configure-the-status-bar-while-app-is-loading-android-only)

You can hide by setting expo config props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try changing the `resizeMode` prop to `cover` in the `splash` object in `app.js` file. It is set to `contain` by default.

Like this:

```js
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splashScreen.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#000000"
    },
```

Comment: I have added that already to my code, it is still showing the same issue.